# How to use custom model binder in Sitecore for a specific WebApi route to pass array?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have my basic Sitecore WebAPI route working just fine. But when I need to pass an array of integers to a custom Sitecore WebApi route, I get 404. How can this be done? Following is what I've tried and works perfectly fine in a typical WebApi route (without sitecore).

**Route**

```cs
AddWebApiRoute(
           name: "StudentsCourseList",
           routeTemplate: "api/v1/students/courselist",
           defaults: new { controller = "StudentsApi", action = "GetCourses" });
```

**Api Controller**

```cs
public class StudentsApi: ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCourses([ModelBinder(typeof(CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder))]long[] courseids)
    {
      var result = await _client.GetCourses(courseids);

        if (result == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }

}
```

**Custom Model Binder**

```cs
public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var key = bindingContext.ModelName;
    var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
    if (val != null)
    {
        var s = val.AttemptedValue;
        if (s != null)
        {
            var elementType = bindingContext.ModelType.GetElementType();
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(elementType);
            var values = Array.ConvertAll(s.Split(new[] { ","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
                x => { return converter.ConvertFromString(x != null ? x.Trim() : x); });

            var typedValues = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Length);

            values.CopyTo(typedValues, 0);

            bindingContext.Model = typedValues;
        }
        else
        {
            // change this line to null if you prefer nulls to empty arrays 
            bindingContext.Model = Array.CreateInstance(bindingContext.ModelType.GetElementType(), 0);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then trying to call as below, return a 404

```cs
/api/v1/students/courselist?courseids=1,2,3
```

Are there any missing parts that are needed to be done as part of Sitecore route setup?

Answer (score 0):

To let Sitecore and WebApi work together in harmony you need to add a processor in the httpRequestBegin pipeline to get the routing to work. You can find information and even source code for this online, e.g. http://patrickdelancy.com/2013/08/sitecore-webapi-living-harmony

Comment: I had edited the question. I have my basic routing, working just fine. It's when I try to add any custom model binder, the route isn't recognized.